# AS3 Can't get array from another class

Tags: actionscript-3, class, return-value

Well, I have a problem, with searching changes of array in ItemProperty class. When i calling to trace item array length, than it gets 0. But in ItemProperty class only in RecieveIndex function item length getting more than 2. Even ReturnData() got 0. The question is how to get final result of this array(Item) in InventoryData class?
That is class, when i got 0:

```
public class InventoryData extends Sprite {

    private var item:ItemProperty = new ItemProperty();

    public function InventoryData(){    
            trace(item.Item);
            trace(item.Item.length);
            //trace(item.ReturnData());
    }
}
```

Class where array was formed. In RecieveIndex method Item length more than 0.

```
public class ItemProperty extends Sprite{
    public var Item:Array = [];
    public function ItemProperty() {
        var connect:Connection = new Connection();
        connect.setRequest("Select", "`inventory`", ["all"], ["all"], InventoryContent);
}
private function InventoryContent(RecieveData:Array):void
{
    var picking:Connection = new Connection();
    picking.setRequest("Select","`weapon`",["all"],["id IN("+RecieveData[0].contents.toString() +    ")"], InventotyData); 
}                 
private function InventotyData(RecieveData:Array):void{                       
    var indexdecode:Connection = new Connection();
    for(var i:uint=0;    i<RecieveData.length;    i++)
    {                  
        indexdecode.loadImageFromBase64(RecieveData[i].id, RecieveIndex);    
    }       
} 
public function RecieveIndex(index:int):void {Item.push(index);     }
public function ReturnData():Array {return Item;}
}
```

Comment: Am I not following? Why do you expect anything else than 0 if array has 0 length when you try to trace it? You do this: create a new instance of InventoryData -> That creates a new item of type ItemProperty -> ItemProperty constructor called, creates new array Item (0 length), then you trace it.

Comment: Yep) The question is how do this right way?) I thought that if i create new ItemPropery that is automatically fills array and i can use it. But its not. :(

Comment: You would have to fill the array in ItemProperty's constructor, or after its declaration in ItemProperty class. If you cannot do that (e.g. you have to wait for some asynchronous event), then you need to dispatch some kind of event once the array is populated. In your InventoryData class you listen to this event and once it occurs, you can use the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this with the event I mentioned in my comment:

```
public class InventoryData extends Sprite {

    private var item:ItemProperty = new ItemProperty();

    public function InventoryData(){    
            item.addEventListener(ItemProperty.ARRAY_READY, onArrayReady);
    }

    private function onArrayReady(e:Event):void {
            trace(item.Item.length);
    }
}
```

In ItemProperty class you declare a new constant:

```
public static const ARRAY_READY:String = "arrayReady";
```

and once you have the array filled with the items you want to retrieve, you add:

```
dispatchEvent(new Event(ARRAY_READY));
```

Comment: Really hate events by the way. :D

Comment: They are really easy to use, you just have to get used to them (+it's handy to know how to extend them). I was hating them too, btw, but it was in the time of as2->as3 migration. :)

Comment: I'll follow your advice. :)

Comment: I've got new problem. Would you like to answer, please? :) In first class i've got array, second changed the array, and third class need to track array changes. How to track changes in third class, do new changes of array and send changed array to the second class?

Comment: One more detail. In the second class i use Event.TouchEvent (it's starling-framework analog of flash Event.Touch) to change the array, and i need to see this changes in third, when in the third i'm changing it too (with Event.TouchEvent).

Comment: You could just dispatch an event upon the array change. In your 3rd class you would listen to `class1instance.addEventListener("whatever event name", doSomething)`. That's all. Note that if your array is in class1 and class2 changes your array, you absolutely NEED to put it to a function and you need to call that function in order to change the array You cannot just get the reference and change it like `a[10]="changed"` cos there is no way how to dispatch an event like that.

Comment: Well, i made container, where i've got array from firstclass(ItemProperty), static. Then in third class created TouchEvent and there changed this static variable by pushing element. Last step was creating instance of thirdclass in second and creating another TouchEvent with changing array. Thank you for all. Sorry for poor English. :)